# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I uploaded my local file to AWS and I did rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production, 
but it shows error... It was working on my local environment but it`s not working on production.

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Migrating to DeleteTagCategories (20170422082951)
== 20170422082951 DeleteTagCategories: migrating ==============================
-- drop_table(:tag_categories)
   (0.2ms)  DROP TABLE `tag_categories`
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'tag_categories': DROP TABLE `tag_categories`
```

What is the best way to solve this error ?

Comment: Check your migrations, it seems that you have a table (`tag_categories`) in development that is missing in production.

Comment: You should use `rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: thank you for your help! yes, that`s right. I had a table (tag_categories)  in development and I had deleted it in development before pushing to production. what should I do to solve this?

Comment: Do as Iceman says: `rake db:schema:load`.

Comment: ummm, I tried that , but it reset my db...

Answer (score 1):

**You should be aware that db:schema:load will remove existing data, so you probably don't want to run that in production if you have any non-seed data you want to keep.**

Since the table (tag_categories) was deleted before it was pushed to production I would have just removed the table manually and not used a migration.

So basically just remove the migration that deletes tag_categories since this table only ever existed on your local machine.

When I am doing Rails development I normally just edit existing migrations and make manual changes where possible instead of creating new migrations for each change. Once I push to production (or source control if working with a team) then I will no longer make additional changes to existing migrations. This cuts down on the number of unnecessary migrations, which can add up quickly.